# TPM: self-test has failed and the TPM has shutdown

Tags: tpm

When I tried to update TPM firmware, the update failed. It prints the error message "self-test has failed and the TPM has shutdown".

I tried to use tpmc commands to re-activate tpm but it didn't work.

Does anyone run into this issue before and resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: This question is really vague and doesn't even really feel like it's programming related.  There are many kinds of TPM, it's pretty much impossible to know what kind you have, or what firmware you were trying to go from/to, or what tpmc commands you might have tried, but again, that all sounds like hardware concerns, not programming related.